# Problem with creating xml file with data from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I struggling with exporting data from one xml to second xml, but the script doesn't throw any error but nothing happened..

I don't know what to do now..

Link to XML file is here: http://shop.dinotoys.cz/content/files/feeds/My_Product_Feed.xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

tree = ET.parse('/home/martin/Plocha/My_Product_Feed.xml') 
  
root = tree.getroot() 

polozky = root[1]
    
data = ET.Element('hracky')

element1 = ET.SubElement(data, 'categories')
element2 = ET.SubElement(data, 'products')
    
s_elem1 = ET.SubElement(element1, 'category')
s_elem2 = ET.SubElement(element2, 'product')

category = "Dino"  
s_elem1.text = category 
    
for p in polozky.findall('Product'):
    s_elem2 = ET.SubElement(element2, 'product')
    img = p.find('MediumImage4').text
    name = p.find('DefaultTitle').text
    status = p.find('IsOrderable').text
    if status == 'True':
        status = "SKLADEM"
    else:
        status = "NENÍ SKLADEM"
    ean = p.find('EAN').text
    try:
        description = p.find('Description_1029').text
    except AttributeError:
        description = ""
        continue
    try:
        category = p.find('Item_Category_Code_Description').text
    except AttributeError:
        category = ""
        continue
    sku = p.find('Id').text
    sku_full = "D" + sku
    
    
    s_elem2_1 = ET.SubElement(s_elem2, 'name')
    s_elem2_2 = ET.SubElement(s_elem2, 'sku')
    s_elem2_3 = ET.SubElement(s_elem2, 'imgurl')
    s_elem2_4 = ET.SubElement(s_elem2, 'status')
    s_elem2_5 = ET.SubElement(s_elem2, 'ean')
    s_elem2_6 = ET.SubElement(s_elem2, 'description')
    s_elem2_7 = ET.SubElement(s_elem2, 'category')
    
    s_elem2_1.text = name
    s_elem2_2.text = sku_full
    s_elem2_3.text = img
    s_elem2_4.text = status
    s_elem2_5.text = ean 
    s_elem2_6.text = description
    s_elem2_7.text = category
    
    xml_content = ET.tostring(data)

    with open('dinoxfeed.xml', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(xml_content)
        f.close()
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: this isn't going to help; but just a nit,  at the end of the file, you don't need a ```f.close()```.

Comment: Explain what is the current output you get and the expected output.

Comment: @balderman ... expected output is new xml file with extracted values from first xml file in specified columns. Current output isn't nothing.. No file, no output in the file..

Comment: @TryingMyBest did you add few `print` lines in the script to see what is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I also tried but still nothing happened.. I don't understant that, because my other script which is based on the same code, works..

Answer (score 0):

On line 9 you try to get the element called "hracky", but there are no such element in the XML file. So data would be an empty node. Furthermore you loop through the various products and do processing, but you don't touch the data variable. You then export only the data variable which contains nothing.

Another thing is that you write the result to the same file for every product which means you overwrite it every time and even if the rest of the code worked you would have only the last product in the file.